# Magento 2: If a module depends on 2 module which loads first?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sequence

In magento there is a module C and it depends on two module A and B. the module.xml of C is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_C" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Test_A"/>
            <module name="Test_B"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Then the order of load module is A,B,C or B,A,C ???

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_C" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_A"/>
            <module name="Magento_B"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>

Answer (score 0):

The first one in the sequence will be the first to be loaded. 
In your case, you will be loading only A, and B.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_C" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_A"/>
            <module name="Magento_B"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

It depends on which module you like to load first, you can interchange both **module A and B.**
UPDATE: The order of loading the module is **A, B, then C.**

Comment: Okay but what if we change that order in composer.json that means here the order is A->B but in composer.json require we provide it as B->A??

Comment: regardless, composer require only checks if module A and B are installed otherwise module C will not install.

Comment: it doesn't really matter if the order in module.xml is A->B but in composer.json require it is B->A.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope my answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Both load orders A,B,C or B,A,C satisfy the sequence you stated in your `module.xml` and there is no guarantee of one or the other.

If you wanted a fixed load order of A,B,C you would need to add a sequence in module B

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_B" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_A"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: But what if module B doesn't depends on module A then it that case if our module A is not installed then our module B also doesn't installed? We only want to make our moduleC dependent on module A and B only in specific order.

Comment: Let's move one step backward - what are you trying to achieve as your end goal? why do you need modules A and B in a specific order?